# Can I Run a nodelet as a regular C++ class

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If i load up a nodelet, from a reguler c++ program, call it's `init` function, and then call `ros::spin()`, will it function as a regular node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125646/can-i-run-a-nodelet-as-a-regular-c++-class/) by [Woodrow Douglass](https://answers.ros.org/users/8766/woodrow-douglass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can make a node out of a nodelet. In fact that's somehow what the nodelet manager does. This might be a very good idea if you have code that might be used/combined somewhere as a nodelet, but also can provide standalone functionality easily.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0